# prevent scroll to one page in pageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

Is there a way to prevent swiping to one specific page in `UIPageViewController`

In my case, I need the left page just to be accessible sometimes,

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain the scenario. Perhaps there is something that fits better.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You will need to set up your page view controller without the page in question, and then add it when you want it to be available.

I would suggest changing your design. Page view controllers aren't intended to handle a case where the set of pages displayed changes. The real world analogy is a book where a page appears sometimes and not others. It doesn't make sense.

Instead you might want to present a modal view controller when you want this special-case VC to be available.